# About the $yy_global_pattern found in smarty

Tags: php, regex, smarty

```
/^(\{\})|^(\{\*([\S\s]*?)\*\})|^(<\?(?:php\w+|=|[a-zA-Z]+)?)|^([     ]*[
]+[  ]*)|^(\{strip\})|^(\{\/strip\})|^(\{literal\})|^(\{\s{1,}\/)|^(\{\s{1,})|^(\{\/)|^(\{)|^(([\S\s]*?)(?=([    ]*[
]+[  ]*|\{|<\?)))|^([\S\s]+)/
```

Anyone know what's `^(<\?(?:php\w+|=|[a-zA-Z]+)?)` for in the above pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matches the beginning of XML processing directives. It seems targeted at php, as it explicitly matches `<?php` and `<?=`.

However, it also matches the XML prologue `<?xml` (or any other sequence, such as `<?xcvsdfadf`) too, so the actual purpose is hard to tell.

- `^`: anchor at the beginning of the line.
- `(`..`)`: grouping, to be referenced later (probably from the code for extraction).
- `\?`: literal `?`.
- `(?:`..`|`..`)`: alternatives (without extraction), matches either of the `|`-separated sub-patterns.

  - `?`: following the alternatives means it can be left out completely as well. (zero or one)
- `php\w+`: literal `php` followed by one or more word characters.
- `=`: literal `=`
- `[a-zA-Z]+`: one or more of upper or lower case characters (A-Z only)

HTH.

Comment: `<?phptest`,why it matches this way?Shouldn't it be `<?php test` ?

Comment: @smarty; I don't think it's looking for php-command, it's just looking for the directive, so it's grabbing both `<?php`, `<?xml` regardless of what comes after it. I have no idea why it's explicitly doing `php` at all, as that one would have been matched by the `[a-zA-Z]+` pattern as well.. perhaps there's something in `\w` group it needs only in the php-case?